# Postgres select output with if statement

Tags: postgresql

I am transferring a project from SQL to PG.
There is such a query in SQL:

```
if(condition)
begin
select * from users;
end
```

The conversion to PG should be with as few changes as possible to maintain the structure of the project
I try to do so:

```
do $$
begin
if(condition)
then
create table v_output as 
select * from users;
end if;
end$$;
select * from v_output;
drop table v_output;
```

In order to get an output, I insert into a temporary table, then select from it
What happens if the condition is FALSE
I get relation `"v_output" does not exist`
It makes sense that if the condition is negative, the table is never created
Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: The table is never created, because `false` will never be `true`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe
Obviously ,
The question is how do I select only if created

Comment: Well, call me stupid, but it was not obvious to me. Perhaps you should add that clarification to the question.

Comment: Also, the SQL Server code you are showing does nothing at all, because 1 is just as obviously never 0. So you are racking your brains to translate code that does nothing. I find it difficult to answer such a question.

Comment: I didn't want to specify the condition,
That's why I wrote like that,
But in reality sometimes it is TRUE sometimes FALSE

Comment: Just select from the table and ignore the error if it doesn't exist

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
It throws an exception

Comment: Yes, I know. Just ignore that exception. What problem exactly are you trying to solve? What is the real, underlying problem here? Why don't you know if your table exists or not? This sounds like an  [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)

Comment: "*how do I select only if created*" - why not just move that `SELECT` inside the `IF` block?

Answer (score 2):

> It makes sense that if the condition is negative, the table is never created.

No, you are mistaken here. It makes sense that the table is never **filled** if the condition is false. However the table must exist regardless of the condition because you later select from it regardless of the condition.

Answer (score 1):

A guess: you don't need pl/pgsql and that temporary table at all. Just do

```
select *
from users
where condition;
```